# Print equation of linear regression model using RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I currently have some rather long inline code for producing an equation of just a simple linear regression:

lm(var1 ~ var2 + var3)

But I could have sworn at some point recently I saw some very succinct inline code to produce an equation of that model, but I seem to not have saved it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

(sorry, I found it, using the equatiomatic package)

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @Daniel_j_iii answer:

```
$lm(Y \sim x)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need need a package for inline equations. Just put you equation in Rmarkdown between 2 $, example below

`$lm(var1 ~ var2 + var3)$`

which looks like this rendered in Rmarkdown

[image]

Comment: That's not precisely what I was aiming for...see here if you want an example (and an awesomely useful package): https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/equatiomatic.html